# Group Gtk.RadioToolButtons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I've been trying for days to find a way to group `RadioToolButtons` in pygobject without success. There is no `*.RadioToolButton.join_group(*)` method like `RadioButton`s.

**Here is what I've been trying:**

```
## Toolbar
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar = Gtk.Toolbar()
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.get_style_context().add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.set_style(Gtk.ToolbarStyle.BOTH)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.radioGroup = list() # *.radioGroup = [] Does not work either.

## Left toolbar separator
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.leftSeparator = Gtk.SeparatorToolItem(draw = False)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.leftSeparator.set_expand(True)

## Overview toggle button
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio = Gtk.RadioToolButton(Gtk.STOCK_HOME)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.set_group(self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.radioGroup)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.set_is_important(True)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.set_label("Overview")
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.connect("clicked", self.on_overviewRadio_clicked)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.set_border_width(4)

## Basic settings toggle button
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.basicRadio = RadioToolButton(Gtk.STOCK_PROPERTIES)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.basicRadio.set_group(self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.radioGroup)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.basicRadio.set_is_important(True)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.basicRadio.set_label("Basic")
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.basicRadio.connect("clicked", self.on_basicRadio_clicked)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.basicRadio.set_border_width(4)

## Right toolbar separator
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.rightSeparator = Gtk.SeparatorToolItem(
    draw = False)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.rightSeparator.set_expand(True)
```

(Not all of my code - `*.show_all()` is not the issue)

**Here is what I get:**

[image: What I get]

What am I doing wrong? How can I group these two buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the second radio button so it's in the first radio button's group using:

```
Gtk.RadioToolButton.new_with_stock_from_widget(first_button, Gtk.STOCK_PROPERTIES)
```

PS. Looks like the UI task you are trying to accomplish might be better done with a `Notebook`?

Comment: BTW Where do you get this knowledge from? The pygobject docs are incredibly scarce and they dont even have a RadioToolButton page.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after all. Do you know if there is a separate method like `join_group()` for `Gtk.RadioToolButton`, or is that the only way?

Comment: I know this by reading the C documentation. The pygobject documentation is lacking, true, but that problem is actively being worked on. I don't think there is a `join_group()` method for the radio tool button.

Comment: I guess Ill have to modify the widget properties manually then... Thanks.